# nginx secure link to rewrite url (PHP)

Tags: security, nginx, hyperlink, url-rewriting

Finally, after two days work of debugging, I made it work completely.
This is how I used it in my scenario.

nginx conf:

```
location ~ /stream/ {
         proxy_no_cache 1;
         proxy_cache_bypass 1;
         secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
         secure_link_md5 "$arg_expires$uri$remote_addr salty";
         if ($secure_link = "") {
                      rewrite ^(.*)$ /error.php?m=$uri&e=$arg_md5&t=$arg_expires;
         }
         if ($secure_link = "0") { return 410; }
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /mp4.php?f=$uri&t=sec; #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/mp4.php?f=$uri&t=sec;
}
```

videotest.php

```
<?php
#This file is used with mp4.php  and secure link module for nginx

$f = (isset($_GET['f'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['f'], ENT_QUOTES) : NULL; #Get file or ID and do basic injection cleaning.

#Various configurations. Expire time, secure key, and paths.
$expires = time()+3100;  # e.g. 2 hours url expiry would be time()+7200;
$prefix = '/stream'; #Secured URI base. Where nginx secure link module is configured. (ex: /stream )
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; #fetch client ip
$server_ip = '172.22.151.68'; #replace with server IP for URLS. (ex: 127.0.0.1)
$url = 'http://' . $server_ip; #Just a clean base URI.
$salt = ' salty'; #change according to nginx directive. Note space before.
$file = $prefix . '/' . $f . '.mp4'; #uri that nginx expects. (ex: /stream +  <file/id> + ext) (/stream/q3-1lI4KWfE.mp4)

function getSecureHash($ip, $uri, $secure_text, $expires){
 $str = $expires . $uri . $ip . $secure_text;
 echo 'nginx expects md5(expires+file+ip secret)<br>';
 echo 'string md5(' . $str .')<br>'; # secure_link_md5 should be "$arg_expires$uri$remote_addr<value of $salt>";
 $tmp = md5( $str, true );
$tmp1 = base64_encode( $tmp ); #base64encode the md5
return str_replace( array('+', '/', '='), array('-', '_', ''), $tmp1 ); #remove extra bits
}

$sec_h = getSecureHash($ip, $file, $salt, $expires); #normal hash
$sec_hi = getSecureHash($server_ip, $file, $salt, $expires); #server hash for curl
echo 'Debug: ' . $sec_h . '<br>';
echo 'Debug 2: ' . $sec_hi . '<br>';
echo 'Expires: ' . $expires . '<br>';
echo 'CURL commands:<br>';
echo 'curl -I ' . $url . $file . '?md5=' . $sec_hi . ' (without exp)<br>';
echo 'curl -I ' . $url . $file . '?md5=' . $sec_hi . '&expires=' . $expires . '<br>';
echo '<br>---<br>';
echo 'New Test:<br>';
echo "MD5 test: echo -n '" . $expires . $file . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $salt . "' | openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 | tr +/ -_ | tr -d =<br>";
exec("echo -n '" . $expires . $file . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $salt . "' | openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 | tr +/ -_ | tr -d =", $output, $retval);
print_r($output);
echo '<br>';
$link =  $url . $file . '?md5=' . $output[0] . '&expires=' . $expires;
echo $link;
echo '<br>Bad link example:';
$blink = $url . $file . '?md5=sumbadcode&expires=012345674';
echo $blink;
?>
<br>
<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="<?php echo $link; ?>" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br>
<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="<?php echo $blink; ?>" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

So that sums up the part that I couldn't get working, which was generating a friendly URL to put into a rewrite'ed link that could be put inside a video player for playing securely. Honestly, once I redirected 403s to error.php
I could see what was going on and what wasn't working. The biggest part was
secure_link_md5 just wasn't right. That and it would redirect silently to a
404 when it did work. So, the access.log became my best friend.

My error.php was simply just doing a foreach on $_GET and php's  getallheaders().

mp4.php takes the input of f and does a file_exists on a file internally then
brings it out through headers in PHP as an attachment.

Here is a demo:

```
<?php
$f = (isset($_GET['f'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['f'], ENT_QUOTES) : NULL;
$t =  (isset($_GET['t'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['t'], ENT_QUOTES) : NULL;
if ($t != NULL) {
$rfile = explode("/stream/", $f);
$file = $rfile[1];
}
else $file = $f;

if (file_exists('/var/www/myfiles/private/' . $file)) {
$mm_type="video/mp4";
$path = 'http://172.22.151.68/private/' . $file;
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
");

readfile($path); // outputs the content of the file

exit();
}
else exit();
?>
```

I could add more security here to make sure the security follows all the way through, but I got it to work and I'm happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've solved this myself. It took quite some time, because I didn't quite understand why it wasn't working. All the guides were the same with a few missing variables, or it only covered usage with their scripts. So I've written out a full clarification guide if anyone runs into this post in the future. 1st issue: URI has to be to the secure URL, not the file you want. Anticipate that these two things work independently. 2nd issue: The guides I was looking at put $secure_link_expires in the md5 directive. Makes it never have success. Editing post to reflect.